# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal while executing query

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sql-server-2016, pyodbc

I'm trying to execute this Python code in Jupyter Notebook, but I'm getting this error.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

query = "SELECT [CodeClient]
      ,[Nom]
      ,[Adresse],[CodePostal],[Telephone],[Fax],[Remarque], 
      [PaiementComptant]
      ,[CodeSituation]
      ,[CrediMax]
      ,[SoldeInitial]
      ,[DateInitial]
      ,[CodeVille]
      ,[CodePersonnel]
      ,[Assurance]
      ,[IdentifiantCnam]
      ,[CNSS]
      ,[CNRPS]
      ,[AUTRE]
      ,[CodeMedecin]
      ,[DateNaissance]
      ,[DateValidite]
      ,[CodeMutuelle]
      ,[MatriculeMutuelle]
      ,[RemisePriseEnCharge]
      ,[CodeOperateur]
      ,[NumeroCIN]
      ,[CarnetCNAM]
        FROM [dbo].[CLIENT]"
df = pd.read_sql(query,conn)

df.head(15)
```

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal.

Can anyone explain this please?

Comment: Try replacing `"` with `"""`

Comment: @user5173426 it workrd! thank you!